# Why system reverts to read-only after attempting push

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to update build.prop, so far with no luck.

> C:\adb_driver2>adb reboot
>
> C:\adb_driver2>adb root
>
> C:\adb_driver2>adb remount remount succeeded
>
> C:\adb_driver2>adb shell mount | grep system

/dev/block/dm-0 /system ext4 **rw**,seclabel,relatime,discard,data=ordered 0 0

> C:\adb_driver2>adb push c:\adb_driver\build.prop /system

failed to copy 'c:\adb_driver\build.prop' to '/system/build.prop': Read-only file system

> C:\adb_driver2>adb shell mount | grep system

/dev/block/dm-0 /system ext4 **ro**,seclabel,relatime,discard,data=ordered 0 0

> C:\adb_driver2>

Any idea why push fails and why system reverts to read-only?
Any known workarounds?

Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was fixed after running this command

> adb disable-verity